# How to simulate, with FIXTURES, a slow REST backend?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to simulate a slow backend in a test application using `FIXTURES`. I am doing the following:

```
App.SlowIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
            Ember.run.later(function() {
                resolve(App.Node.find());
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
});
```

I was expecting that this would behave similarly to a slow REST backend, namely:

1. The request is sent
2. Route is activated, and the template is rendered
3. Reply arrives from backend
4. Now the data is updated in the template

Instead, this is roughly what is happening, as far as I can tell:

1. The request is sent
2. No rendering of the template is performed, the route is not yet activated.
3. Once the reply "arrives" (`resolve(App.Node.find());`) the route is activated
4. The template is rendered, and since the data is already available, it is also displayed

How can I more accurately simulate a slow REST backend? How can I make sure that the router is activating the view/template *before* the reply arrives?

Answer (score 4):

DS.FixtureAdapter has a `latency` property that defaults to 50 milliseconds. You can change this by instantiating the adapter manually when you create your store.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({ latency: 1000 });
});
```

As of Ember 1.0.0-rc.6, it is expected behavior for a route to wait for the model's promise to resolve before transitioning. If you don't want the route to wait, don't return a promise (something with a `then` method) from your `model` hook. Return a regular object, one that's already loaded, or a proxy. Then load the model later, in your `setupController` hook, for example.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, changing the latency of the `FixtureAdapter` would affect all routes. I am interested in tweaking this on a route-by-route basis, so it will not work in my case. The second approach that you suggest looks more promising. Could you provide some sample code?